# plugin for latest version and FAQ's

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I am developing a new plugin for wordpress. I will put it on own site which is developed in  wordpress, so other can download and use it.

I want to give the revision facility like updated version of plugin with old version available on site and FAQ's etc. is there any plugin which can control this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

WordPress was only really developed to manage revisions of posts, not software (as far as I know), but [GitHub](https://github.com/) is pretty cool, you should definitely look into it. You can use it to help you develop and get others to help out too. It makes your work publicly available without you having to purchase any hosting or worry about setting up a site for it.

There is a little bit of a learning curve for git, but once you get the hang of it, you'll be thankful you started using it.

And just to clarify, git is a version control system. GitHub is a place where you can keep your git repository, and it makes your life super easy in doing so.

**Here are some research links for you...**

https://github.com/

http://git-scm.com/

---

If you wanted to, you could still create that Wordpress site, but have your commits or tags (not too sure about the latter) tied to a feed, so whenever a new one is up on GitHub, it gets picked up by your site automatically.

Just some food for thought anyway :)...

Good luck!

Comment: Actually its a client server plugin. So I have to develop the server and server site for it. Thats why I ask for the plugin if available. Your opinion is right I will place the copy of it there as well. However it is special pupose plugin for deaf. To examin the listing power.